# Self-Studying Algebraic Geometry: Finding $f$ in $I(V(J))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Problem 4.1.2 in *Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms* asks:

> Let $J=\langle x^2+y^2-1,y-1\rangle$. Find $f \in I(V(J))$ such that $f \notin J.$

I started by trying to get an idea of what $V(J)$ is- the set of common zeroes of $x^2+y^2-1$ and $y-1$. I figure both polynomials are zero at the point $(0,1)$.

Not quite sure where to go from here- any help is welcome.

Comment: You're right about what $V(J)$ is. Can you use that to write down $I(V(J))$? (Hint: what's the simplest pair of equations you could use to cut out that point?)

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh I'm going to guess (x, y-1)?

Comment: Exactly. And if you don't want to trust me, @PVAL just explained everything! :)

Comment: So he did! I just saw his comment. Thank you to the both of you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $x^2+y^2-1=x^2+(y-1)(y+1)$, we have $J=(x^2,y-1)$. Hence $I(V(J))=(x,y-1)$.

Comment: Are you using the Nullstellensatz for the "hence" or something easier/weaker?

Comment: @aerdna91 You can use the nullstellansatz or just directly compute $V(J)$.